# UIBezierPath Subtract Path

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibezierpath

By using `[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:byRoundingCorners:cornerRadii:]`, I am able to create a rounded view, such as this:

[image: rounded view]

How could I subtract another path from this one (or some other way), to create a path like this:

[image: subtracted view]

Is there any way I can do something like this?
Pseudocode:

```
UIBezierPath *bigMaskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:bigView.bounds 
                                 byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft|UIRectCornerTopRight)
                                       cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(18, 18)];
UIBezierPath *smallMaskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:smalLView.bounds 
                                     byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft|UIRectCornerTopRight)
                                           cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(18, 18)];

UIBezierPath *finalPath = [UIBezierPath pathBySubtractingPath:smallMaskPath fromPath:bigMaskPath];
```

Comment: Note that "subtracting paths" is a whole other thing. Above you're simply "making a whole" using winding.   It's dead easy (1) hole.reverse  (2) outside.add(hole).  Done!  See answer.

Comment: err, I meant "hole" not "whole"  :)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If you want to stroke the subtracted path, you are on your own.  Apple doesn't provide an API that returns (or just strokes) the subtraction of one path from another.

If you just want to fill the subtracted path (as in your example image), you can do it using the clipping path.  You have to use a trick, though.  When you add a path to the clipping path, the new clipping path is the *intersection* of the old clipping path and the added path.  So if you just add `smallMaskPath` to the clipping path, you will end up filling only the region inside `smallMaskPath`, which is the opposite of what you want.

What you need to do is intersect the existing clipping path with the *inverse* of `smallMaskPath`.  Fortunately, you can do that pretty easily using the even-odd winding rule.  You can read about the even-odd rule in the [*Quartz 2D Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH211-TPXREF106).

The basic idea is that we create a compound path with two subpaths: your `smallMaskPath` and a huge rectangle that completely encloses your `smallMaskPath` and every other pixel you might want to fill.  Because of the even-odd rule, every pixel inside of `smallMaskPath` will be treated as outside of the compound path, and every pixel outside of `smallMaskPath` will be treated as inside of the compound path.

So let's create this compound path.  We'll start with the huge rectangle.  And there is no rectangle more huge than the infinite rectangle:

```
UIBezierPath *clipPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectInfinite];
```

Now we make it into a compound path by adding `smallMaskPath` to it:

```
[clipPath appendPath:smallMaskPath];
```

Next we set the path to use the even-odd rule:

```
clipPath.usesEvenOddFillRule = YES;
```

Before we clip to this path, we should save the graphics state so that we can undo the change to the clipping path when we're done:

```
CGContextSaveGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()); {
```

Now we can modify the clipping path:

```
    [clipPath addClip];
```

and we can fill `bigMaskPath`:

```
    [[UIColor orangeColor] setFill];
    [bigMaskPath fill];
```

Finally we restore the graphics state, undoing the change to the clipping path:

```
} CGContextRestoreGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
```

Here's the code all together in case you want to copy/paste it:

```
UIBezierPath *clipPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectInfinite];
[clipPath appendPath:smallMaskPath];
clipPath.usesEvenOddFillRule = YES;

CGContextSaveGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()); {
    [clipPath addClip];
    [[UIColor orangeColor] setFill];
    [bigMaskPath fill];
} CGContextRestoreGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
```

Comment: This is way more work than is needed.  It's simple to create a path consisting of the inner and outer roundrects and fill it with the even-odd rule.  You don't need to do anything to the clip path.

Comment: Your answer is simpler when smallMaskPath is entirely contained by bigPathMask, as in Jaden10's example.  In the general case where smallMaskPath also includes pixels outside of bigMaskPath, your simpler approach won't work.

Comment: I like the style you use to put the GState between braces!!

Comment: There's a simpler way to attain this, just set the blend mode on the context to clear.

Comment: @TaylorHalliday If there are non-clear pixels inside `smallMaskPath` and you don't want to make them clear, you'll have to compose your orange arch in another image first, then draw that image into your original context.

Comment: @robmayoff Yes, absolutely. Just wanted to share because I was having issues with the EOFill when you had multiple stacked paths on each other (think a 3-circle venn diagram). Setting the blend mode wiped them all out, which is the effect I wanted. If you wanted to show something under them, then you would just push/pop the context appropriately and only have the blend mode apply to the circles.

Comment: @robmayoff I too may be misunderstanding something on this one.  You just use flip winding, and use the non-zero rule.  That works perfectly if the "hole" is fully contained, or, if it is a cut-out from the edge.  Again I may not have understood your qualifications.

Answer (score 95):

Actually there is a much simpler way for most cases, example in Swift:

```
path.append(cutout.reversing())
```

This works because the default fill rule is the [non-zero winding rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonzero-rule).

Comment: Wow! Super elegant and amazing!

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Way simpler than the accepted answer :)

Comment: NSResponder's answer was good, but this one is great! Thanks!

Comment: this worked perfectly for cutting one circle out of another - thank you!

Comment: Holy moley. This is great. Thank you!

Comment: is 'cutout' the name of the second path?

Comment: @BooberBunz yeah

Comment: How can I get the path of a CGRect ? doesn't seem to exist a function

Comment: @Marin Check https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624359-init

Answer (score 34):

This should do it, adjust sizes as you like:

```
CGRect outerRect = {0, 0, 200, 200};
CGRect innerRect  = CGRectInset(outerRect,  30, 30);

UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:outerRect cornerRadius:10];

[path appendPath:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:innerRect cornerRadius:5]];
path.usesEvenOddFillRule = YES;

[[UIColor orangeColor] set];
[path fill];
```

Another really simple way to get the effect you're after is to just draw the outer roundrect, change colors, and draw the inner one over it.

Comment: This looks really promising for what I'm trying to do, however, UIBezierPath and NSColor don't mix since one is iOS and the other is OSX. Do you, by chance, have a more complete example that works on iOS?

Comment: Create a `CAShapeLayer` and add it as a sublayer of your view, then set the new layer's `path` and `frame` properties. You can set the `path` property to the `CGPath` version of the `UIBezierPath`, e.g. `[uiBezierPathInstance CGPath]`.

Answer (score 14):

Using @Patrick Pijnappel answer, you can prepare test playground for quick testing

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 647))
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

let someView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:50, y: 50, width:250, height:250))
someView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
view.addSubview(someView)

let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.frame = someView.bounds
shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: someView.bounds, 
                               byRoundingCorners: [UIRectCorner.bottomLeft,UIRectCorner.bottomRight] ,
                                cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0)).cgPath

someView.layer.mask = shapeLayer
someView.layer.masksToBounds = true

let rect = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:200, height:100)
let cornerRadius:CGFloat = 5
let subPathSideSize:CGFloat = 25

let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
let leftSubPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x:0, y:rect.height / 2), 
                                radius: subPathSideSize / 2, startAngle:  CGFloat(Double.pi / 2), endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi + Double.pi / 2), clockwise: false)
leftSubPath.close()

let rightSubPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x:rect.width, y:rect.height / 2), 
                               radius: subPathSideSize / 2, startAngle:  CGFloat(Double.pi / 2), endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi + Double.pi / 2), clockwise: true)
rightSubPath.close()

path.append(leftSubPath)
path.append(rightSubPath.reversing())
path.append(path)

let mask = CAShapeLayer()
mask.frame = shapeLayer.bounds
mask.path = path.cgPath

someView.layer.mask = mask 

view
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I copy paste your code to Playground but there is no cutout @gbk

Comment: @JeffersonSetiawan check my edit, typo in code sorry

Comment: Thanks sir, for you help. Finally am able to achieve this task.

Comment: Good answer, but how to add shadow to red element?

Comment: Just create shadow path with same bezierpath and add to layer or to specially-created layer for shadow below current one

Answer (score 11):

## 2019 - too easy

I'm surprised at the other answers, because this is extremely easy to do.  Could be there's some requirements I don't understand. But:

```
p = UIBezierPath(rect: .. )
let hole = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: ... )
p.append(hole.reversing())
p.usesEvenOddFillRule = false
```

This does work perfectly whether or not you have cutting.

## There is *no* problem, *even if* they do overlap:

> [image]

and

> [image]

(This is a great way to make a "notch" or "indentation".)

The technique is

1. Outer path goes cw, inner path goes ccw
2. Use counting rule aka non-zero-rule

(In the example, I'm literally using it as a mask on a UIView...)

```
layerToUseAsUIViewMask.path = p
layer.mask = layerToUseAsUIViewMask
```

To save anyone typing the hole code ...

```
let hole = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(
    origin: CGPoint(x: 70, y: 10), .. use -10 for the second demo above.
    size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
)
```

*Note* If you're not sure which way the two paths are running, of course just try each of

```
p.append(hole.reversing()) // that's acw currently on iOS
```

and

```
p.append(hole) // that's cw currently on iOS
```

until it works.

---

Similar useful tip:

## Make a glow box:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59092828/294884

Answer (score 5):

I've been beating my head against the wall trying to figure out how to do this with multiple overlapping CGPaths. If you overlap more than once, it refills with the solutions provided above. It turns out the way to truly attain a 'subtract' effect with multiple overlapping paths is to just set the context's blend mode to clear.

`CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeClear);`

Answer (score 2):

Patrick provided an improvement/alternative to user NSResponder's answer by using the [non-zero winding rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonzero-rule). Here is a full implementation in Swift for anyone that is looking for an expanded answer.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: 200, height: 200), false, 0.0)
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

let rectPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200), cornerRadius: 10)
var cutoutPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRectMake(30, 30, 140, 140), cornerRadius: 10)

rectPath.appendPath(cutoutPath.bezierPathByReversingPath())

UIColor.orangeColor().set()
outerForegroundPath.fill()

let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

[Here's a gist of this.](https://gist.github.com/timgcarlson/5ae77b5f9c57c1cf96f7aac32ee6a03d)

You can put this into a Storyboard to see and play around with the output.

[image: The result]

Answer (score 0):

Here is two transparent hole on View:

[image]

```
@IBDesignable
class HoleView: UIView {
    
    @IBInspectable
    var radius1: CGFloat = 10 { didSet { updateMask() } }
    
    @IBInspectable
    var XPositionPercent1: CGFloat = 90 { didSet { updateMask() } }
    
    @IBInspectable
    var YPositionPercent1: CGFloat = 50 { didSet { updateMask() } }
    
    
    @IBInspectable
    var radius2: CGFloat = 10 { didSet { updateMask() } }
    
    @IBInspectable
    var XPositionPercent2: CGFloat = 10 { didSet { updateMask() } }
    
    @IBInspectable
    var YPositionPercent2: CGFloat = 50 { didSet { updateMask() } }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        updateMask()
    }
    
    private func updateMask() {
        
        let path = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds)
        path.usesEvenOddFillRule = false
        
        
        // MARK: Hole 1
        let XPos1 = (bounds.width * XPositionPercent1) / 100
        let YPos1 = (bounds.height * YPositionPercent1) / 100
        let center1 = CGPoint(x: XPos1, y: YPos1)
        
        let hole1 = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center1,
                                 radius: radius1,
                                 startAngle: 0,
                                 endAngle: 2 * .pi,
                                 clockwise: true)
        path.append(hole1)
        
        // MARK: Hole 2
        let XPos2 = (bounds.width * XPositionPercent2) / 100
        let YPos2 = (bounds.height * YPositionPercent2) / 100
        let center2 = CGPoint(x: XPos2, y: YPos2)
        let hole2 = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center2,
                                 radius: radius2,
                                 startAngle: 0,
                                 endAngle: 2 * .pi,
                                 clockwise: true)
        path.append(hole2)
        
        
        
        let mask1 = CAShapeLayer()
        mask1.fillRule = .evenOdd
        mask1.path = path.cgPath
        
        layer.mask = mask1
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of subtracting, I was able to solve by creating a `CGPath` using `CGPathAddLineToPoint` and `CGPathAddArcToPoint`. This can also be done with a `UIBiezerPath` with similar code.