# Problems with corner radius and drop shadow for button

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, shadow, cornerradius

I'm trying to create a button with **rounded corners** and a **drop shadow**. No matter how I switch up, the button will not display correctly. I've tried `masksToBounds = false` and `masksToBounds = true`, but either the corner radius works and the shadow does not or the shadow works and the corner radius doesn't clip the corners of the button.

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

@IBDesignable
class Button : UIButton
{
    @IBInspectable var masksToBounds: Bool    = false                {didSet{updateLayerProperties()}}
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius : CGFloat = 0                    {didSet{updateLayerProperties()}}
    @IBInspectable var borderWidth  : CGFloat = 0                    {didSet{updateLayerProperties()}}
    @IBInspectable var borderColor  : UIColor = UIColor.clearColor() {didSet{updateLayerProperties()}}
    @IBInspectable var shadowColor  : UIColor = UIColor.clearColor() {didSet{updateLayerProperties()}}
    @IBInspectable var shadowOpacity: CGFloat = 0                    {didSet{updateLayerProperties()}}
    @IBInspectable var shadowRadius : CGFloat = 0                    {didSet{updateLayerProperties()}}
    @IBInspectable var shadowOffset : CGSize  = CGSizeMake(0, 0)     {didSet{updateLayerProperties()}}

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
    {
        updateLayerProperties()
    }

    func updateLayerProperties()
    {
        self.layer.masksToBounds = masksToBounds
        self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        self.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor
        self.layer.shadowColor = shadowColor.CGColor
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = CFloat(shadowOpacity)
        self.layer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
        self.layer.shadowOffset = shadowOffset
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll want to put the shadow and clipping on different layers.  And setting up the layer properties in `drawRect` isn't a very good idea.  Better to put them in `initWithCoder`.

Comment: Just for anyone googling here, as often happens with very old questions, the top answer here while generally correct ***now has some critical mistakes***.  (I put in a corrected answer.) Most people, especially me, blindly copy and paste from the top SO answer - be careful if it is a very **old** QA!   (It's 2020 now - someone will have to replace my answer in 5 years!)

Comment: If your button has an image then you will need to add corner radius also the imageView of the button. This will be the simplest way

Answer (score 172, accepted):

The following Swift 5 / iOS 12 code shows how to set a subclass of `UIButton` that allows to create instances with rounded corners and shadow around it:

```
import UIKit

final class CustomButton: UIButton {

    private var shadowLayer: CAShapeLayer!

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        if shadowLayer == nil {
            shadowLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            shadowLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: 12).cgPath
            shadowLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

            shadowLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
            shadowLayer.shadowPath = shadowLayer.path
            shadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2.0, height: 2.0)
            shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
            shadowLayer.shadowRadius = 2

            layer.insertSublayer(shadowLayer, at: 0)
            //layer.insertSublayer(shadowLayer, below: nil) // also works
        }        
    }

}
```

According to your needs, you may add a `UIButton` in your Storyboard and set its class to `CustomButton` or you may create an instance of `CustomButton` programmatically. The following `UIViewController` implementation shows how to create and use a `CustomButton` instance programmatically:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let button = CustomButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
        view.addSubview(button)

        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let horizontalConstraint = button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
        let verticalConstraint = button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)        
        let widthConstraint = button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
        let heightConstraint = button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([horizontalConstraint, verticalConstraint, widthConstraint, heightConstraint])
    }

}
```

---

The previous code produces the image below in the iPhone simulator:

[image]

Comment: with iOS i had problems with my old implementation, now it works. Thank you!

Comment: How do you call the class from your main view controller @POB?

Comment: This does not seem to work if you want to make a circle (corner radius is half the width, if the button is square). The edges of the shadow and button seem to be cut off.

Comment: Is there a way to trim the shadowlayer, keeping only the visible part?

Comment: Since the shadowlayer is a sublayer of the button's own layer, which has `masksToBounds = YES` to show rounded corners, won't the shadow also be clipped off?

Comment: I got a subclass of UIView working; no real changes from the class in this answer, just change the super class to UIView. A problem I was having was likely due to using a uivisualeffectview with blur etc added onto the view. I fixed that by applying the same rounded corners value to the uivisualeffectview also. Answer added: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50206346/129202

Comment: @JohanTingbacke I think I fixed that by setting the fill color of the shadow layer to UIColor.clear, see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50206346/129202

Comment: That works fin but i'm not able to change button background anymore. This is probably because of shadowLayer.fillColor. What do you suggest? Thanks !

Comment: Thanks for clear answer, I'm trying to use your code for UILabel but it doesn't work and my label text doesn't appear, do you know any solution for rounded uilabel with shadow?

Comment: I tried to change this type to UILabel, then add a gradient layer, then add text and it didn't work?! What do I do?

Comment: @GrayFox When you need to change button background color you can apply the same change to the layer fillColor, but when comes to setImage it seems won't work.

Comment: you saved my time & effort, I tried almost everything. Thanks. Works fine.

Comment: This is great! Just remember to set the background colour of the button to clear...

Comment: @ImanouPetit   **guys, if you're still reading, this answer has a serious error.  You have to - of course! - set the path (not to mention the frame!!!!!) every time layout runs!**   I put in a correct answer for the record, cheers

Comment: this is not working for me on a generic UIView. The shadow sits behind the view, but does not overflow around its edges

Comment: Man, `layoutSubviews` is called multiple times and it is not guaranteed that you get a valid frame on its first call. Moreover sometimes even on after its last call you may get invalid frame.

Answer (score 48):

My custom **button** with some **shadow** and **rounded corners**, I use it directly within the `Storyboard` with no need to *touch* it programmatically.

> **Swift 4**

```
class RoundedButtonWithShadow: UIButton {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height/2
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, cornerRadius: self.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 3.0)
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Quick and easy.

Comment: For me it did the trick when I re-placed the code in `layoutSubviews()`.

Answer (score 18):

To expand on Imanou's post, it's possible to programmatically add the shadow layer in the custom button class

```
@IBDesignable class CustomButton: UIButton {
    var shadowAdded: Bool = false

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
            layer.masksToBounds = cornerRadius > 0
        }
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawRect(rect)

        if shadowAdded { return }
        shadowAdded = true

        let shadowLayer = UIView(frame: self.frame)
        shadowLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        shadowLayer.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor
        shadowLayer.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: self.cornerRadius).CGPath
        shadowLayer.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
        shadowLayer.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        shadowLayer.layer.shadowRadius = 1
        shadowLayer.layer.masksToBounds = true
        shadowLayer.clipsToBounds = false

        self.superview?.addSubview(shadowLayer)
        self.superview?.bringSubviewToFront(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: You're masking the layer's shadow and I really would not recommend putting the shadow view on the button's superview.

Answer (score 15):

An alternative way to get more usable and consistent button.

Swift 2:

```
func getImageWithColor(color: UIColor, size: CGSize, cornerRadius:CGFloat) -> UIImage {
    let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 1)
    UIBezierPath(
        roundedRect: rect,
        cornerRadius: cornerRadius
        ).addClip()
    color.setFill()
    UIRectFill(rect)
    let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}

let button = UIButton(type: .Custom)
button.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 50)
button.setTitle("My Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
self.addSubview(button)

let image = getImageWithColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), size: button.frame.size, cornerRadius: 5)
button.setBackgroundImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

button.layer.shadowRadius = 5
button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
button.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1)
button.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

Swift 3:

```
func getImageWithColor(_ color: UIColor, size: CGSize, cornerRadius:CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
    color.setFill()
    UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: cornerRadius).addClip()
    color.setFill()
    UIRectFill(rect)
    let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}

let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
button.frame = CGRect(x:20, y:20, width:200, height:50)
button.setTitle("My Button", for: .normal)
button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
self.addSubview(button)

if let image = getImageWithColor(UIColor.white, size: button.frame.size, cornerRadius: 5) {
    button.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .normal)
}

button.layer.shadowRadius = 5
button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
button.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width:0, height:1)
button.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

Comment: This method is best since you can have a different background color for .normal and highlighted

Comment: Nice. Tried many different methods of getting background colour, corner radius and shadows working in my buttons, but this was the only way that worked! Thanks!

Comment: This is the perfect solution, thanks for this! One note, if using UIButton inside UITableViewCell, programatically, this have to be placed inside layoutSubviews().

Comment: There is one issue, when I tested it on simulator for iPhone 5s (iOS 12.4), the button title color does not take effect and remains white. Unfortunately I don't have an actual device with the same iOS version to test this out with.  I had to shift it to layoutSubviews for it to work. Not fully sure why.

Answer (score 14):

**Swift 5 &**
**No need of "UIBezierPath"**

```
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    view.clipsToBounds = true
    view.layer.masksToBounds = false
    view.layer.shadowRadius = 7
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.6
    view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 5)
    view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
```

Comment: It never adds any corner radius to the view and the reason why you need `UIBezierPath` is for performance reasons in case you need to reuse that particular view.

Comment: @SharkesMonken "NEVER" really!!!! ? Please check once again. I am using this method all over my project. And if you have any doubt, please check this video 
 https://youtu.be/5qdF5ocDU7w

Comment: please check the video

Comment: It does not work if you have a background image for the button. The images corner radius does not get set

Comment: @SharkesMonken I was looking for some solution regarding shadows & look what I found here is your comment     Nice to meet you, man.

Comment: I guess it has some drawbacks and hidden issues, but it's working good so far with the UIButton with just a text.

Answer (score 4):

Refactored [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25475536/129202) to support any view. Subclass your view from this and it should have rounded corners. If you add something like a UIVisualEffectView as a subview to this view you likely need to use the same rounded corners on that UIVisualEffectView or it won't have rounded corners.

[image: Rounded corners with shadow for UIView - screenshot also uses a blur which is a normal UIVisualEffectView which also has rounded corners]

```
/// Inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25475536/129202
class ViewWithRoundedcornersAndShadow: UIView {
    private var theShadowLayer: CAShapeLayer?

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        if self.theShadowLayer == nil {
            let rounding = CGFloat.init(22.0)

            let shadowLayer = CAShapeLayer.init()
            self.theShadowLayer = shadowLayer
            shadowLayer.path = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: rounding).cgPath
            shadowLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

            shadowLayer.shadowPath = shadowLayer.path
            shadowLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            shadowLayer.shadowRadius = CGFloat.init(3.0)
            shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = Float.init(0.2)
            shadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize.init(width: 0.0, height: 4.0)

            self.layer.insertSublayer(shadowLayer, at: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Exact solution for 2020 syntax

```
import UIKit
class ColorAndShadowButton: UIButton {
    override init(frame: CGRect) { super.init(frame: frame), common() }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { super.init(coder: aDecoder), common() }
    private func common() {
        // UIButton is tricky: you MUST set the clear bg in bringup;  NOT in layout
        backgroundColor = .clear
        clipsToBounds = false
        layer.insertSublayer(colorAndShadow, below: layer)
    }
    
   lazy var colorAndShadow: CAShapeLayer = {
        let s = CAShapeLayer()
        // set your button color HERE (NOT on storyboard)
        s.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        // now set your shadow color/values
        s.shadowColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        s.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 10)
        s.shadowOpacity = 1
        s.shadowRadius = 10
        // now add the shadow
        layer.insertSublayer(s, at: 0)
        return s
    }()
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        // you MUST layout these two EVERY layout cycle:
        colorAndShadow.frame = bounds
        colorAndShadow.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: 12).cgPath
    }
}
```

> [image]

- Note that the very old top answer here is correct but has a **critical error**

### Note that `UIButton` is unfortunately quite different from `UIView` in iOS.

- Due to a strange behavior in iOS, you must set the background color (which of course must be clear in this case) **in initialization, not in layout**. You could just set it clear in storyboard (but you usually click it to be some solid color simply so you can see it when working in storyboard.)

In general combos of shadows/rounding are a real pain in iOS. Similar solutions:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57465440/294884 - image + rounded + shadows
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41553784/294884 - two-corner problem
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59092828/294884 - "shadows + hole" or "glowbox" problem
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57400842/294884 - the "border AND gap" problem
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57514286/294884 - basic "adding" beziers

Comment: What is `backgroundAndShadow`?

Comment: sorry should be colorAndShadow I think, changed

Answer (score 3):

**Corner Radius with Shadow**

Short and simple way !!!!!

```
extension CALayer {
    func applyCornerRadiusShadow(
        color: UIColor = .black,
        alpha: Float = 0.5,
        x: CGFloat = 0,
        y: CGFloat = 2,
        blur: CGFloat = 4,
        spread: CGFloat = 0,
        cornerRadiusValue: CGFloat = 0)
    {
        cornerRadius = cornerRadiusValue
        shadowColor = color.cgColor
        shadowOpacity = alpha
        shadowOffset = CGSize(width: x, height: y)
        shadowRadius = blur / 2.0
        if spread == 0 {
            shadowPath = nil
        } else {
            let dx = -spread
            let rect = bounds.insetBy(dx: dx, dy: dx)
            shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: rect).cgPath
        }
    }
}
```

Use of code

```
btn.layer.applyCornerRadiusShadow(color: .black, 
                            alpha: 0.38, 
                            x: 0, y: 3, 
                            blur: 10, 
                            spread: 0, 
                            cornerRadiusValue: 24)
```

> No need maskToBound

Please verify clipsToBounds is false.

***OUTPUT***

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the code but doesn't work for me, why? Please check the image: https://imgur.com/dY5M3BL

Comment: @Mc.Lover did you used maskToBound? or clipsToBounds?

Answer (score 2):

To improve PiterPan's answer and show a real shadow (not just a background with no blur) with a circular button in Swift 3:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myButton.layer.masksToBounds = false
    myButton.layer.cornerRadius = myButton.frame.height/2
    myButton.clipsToBounds = true
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    addShadowForRoundedButton(view: self.view, button: myButton, opacity: 0.5)
}

func addShadowForRoundedButton(view: UIView, button: UIButton, opacity: Float = 1) {
    let shadowView = UIView()
    shadowView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    shadowView.layer.opacity = opacity
    shadowView.layer.shadowRadius = 5
    shadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.35
    shadowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    shadowView.layer.cornerRadius = button.bounds.size.width / 2
    shadowView.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: button.frame.origin.x, y: button.frame.origin.y), size: CGSize(width: button.bounds.width, height: button.bounds.height))
    self.view.addSubview(shadowView)
    view.bringSubview(toFront: button)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extension to drop shadow and corner radius

```
extension UIView {

func dropShadow(color: UIColor, opacity: Float = 0.5, offSet: CGSize, shadowRadius: CGFloat = 1, scale: Bool = true, cornerRadius: CGFloat) {
    let shadowLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shadowLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: cornerRadius).cgPath
    shadowLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    shadowLayer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
    shadowLayer.shadowPath = shadowLayer.path
    shadowLayer.shadowOffset = offSet
    shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = opacity
    shadowLayer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
    layer.insertSublayer(shadowLayer, at: 0)
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that will work!

```swift
extension UIView {

    func applyShadowWithCornerRadius(color:UIColor, opacity:Float, radius: CGFloat, edge:AIEdge, shadowSpace:CGFloat)    {

        var sizeOffset:CGSize = CGSize.zero
        switch edge {
        case .Top:
            sizeOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: -shadowSpace)
        case .Left:
            sizeOffset = CGSize(width: -shadowSpace, height: 0)
        case .Bottom:
            sizeOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: shadowSpace)
        case .Right:
            sizeOffset = CGSize(width: shadowSpace, height: 0)


        case .Top_Left:
            sizeOffset = CGSize(width: -shadowSpace, height: -shadowSpace)
        case .Top_Right:
            sizeOffset = CGSize(width: shadowSpace, height: -shadowSpace)
        case .Bottom_Left:
            sizeOffset = CGSize(width: -shadowSpace, height: shadowSpace)
        case .Bottom_Right:
            sizeOffset = CGSize(width: shadowSpace, height: shadowSpace)


        case .All:
            sizeOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        case .None:
            sizeOffset = CGSize.zero
        }

        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height / 2
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true;

        self.layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = opacity
        self.layer.shadowOffset = sizeOffset
        self.layer.shadowRadius = radius
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false

        self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:self.bounds, cornerRadius:self.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath
    }
}

enum AIEdge:Int {
    case
    Top,
    Left,
    Bottom,
    Right,
    Top_Left,
    Top_Right,
    Bottom_Left,
    Bottom_Right,
    All,
    None
}
```

Finally, to apply shadow with corner radius call as per below:

```swift
viewRounded.applyShadowWithCornerRadius(color: .gray, opacity: 1, radius: 15, edge: AIEdge.All, shadowSpace: 15)
```

Result Image

[image]

**UPDATE**: If you don't see the expected output then try calling the extension method from **Main Thread**, that will work for sure!

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    viewRounded.applyShadowWithCornerRadius(color: .gray, opacity: 1, radius: 15, edge: AIEdge.All, shadowSpace: 15)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### UIButton Extension

Many people have proposed using a custom class of `UIButton` which is totally fine. Just in case you want an extension, like me, here's one. *Written in Swift 5.*

```
extension UIButton {
    /// Adds a shadow to the button, with a corner radius
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - corner: The corner radius to apply to the shadow and button
    ///   - color: The color of the shaodw
    ///   - opacity: The opacity of the shadow
    ///   - offset: The offset of the shadow
    ///   - radius: The radius of the shadow
    func addShadow(corner: CGFloat = 20, color: UIColor = .black, opacity: Float = 0.3, offset: CGSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 5), radius: CGFloat = 5) {
        let shadowLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.cornerRadius = corner
        shadowLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: corner).cgPath
        shadowLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shadowLayer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
        shadowLayer.shadowPath = shadowLayer.path
        shadowLayer.shadowOffset = offset
        shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = opacity
        shadowLayer.shadowRadius = radius
        
        layer.insertSublayer(shadowLayer, at: 0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for those are searching about circle image with shadow you can use new
**Filled Button** with capsule **cornerStyle** and apply shadow with code after this also you can try using different cornerStyle sizes from menu there:

```
    backButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    backButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
    backButton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    backButton.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

[image: set Corner style in filled Button]

[image: final shape]

Answer (score -1):

If somebody need add shadows to **rounded** buttons in Swift 3.0, here is a good method to do it.

```
func addShadowForRoundedButton(view: UIView, button: UIButton, shadowColor: UIColor, shadowOffset: CGSize, opacity: Float = 1) {
    let shadowView = UIView()
    shadowView.backgroundColor = shadowColor
    shadowView.layer.opacity = opacity
    shadowView.layer.cornerRadius = button.bounds.size.width / 2
    shadowView.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: button.frame.origin.x + shadowOffset.width, y: button.frame.origin.y + shadowOffset.height), size: CGSize(width: button.bouds.width, height: button.bounds.height))
    self.view.addSubview(shadowView)
    view.bringSubview(toFront: button)
}
```

Use this method in `func viewDidLayoutSubviews()` as bellow:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    addShadowForRoundedButton(view: self.view, button: button, shadowColor: .black, shadowOffset: CGSize(width: 2, height: 2), opacity: 0.5)
}
```

The effect of this method is:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can create a protocol and conform it to you UIView, UIButton, Cell or whatever you want like that:

```
protocol RoundedShadowable: class {
    var shadowLayer: CAShapeLayer? { get set }
    var layer: CALayer { get }
    var bounds: CGRect { get }
}
​
extension RoundedShadowable {
    func applyShadowOnce(withCornerRadius cornerRadius: CGFloat, andFillColor fillColor: UIColor) {
        if self.shadowLayer == nil {
            let shadowLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            shadowLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: cornerRadius).cgPath
            shadowLayer.fillColor = fillColor.cgColor
            shadowLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            shadowLayer.shadowPath = shadowLayer.path
            shadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 2.0)
            shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
            shadowLayer.shadowRadius = 3
            self.layer.insertSublayer(shadowLayer, at: 0)
            self.shadowLayer = shadowLayer
        }
    }
}
​
class RoundShadowView: UIView, RoundedShadowable {

    var shadowLayer: CAShapeLayer?
    private let cornerRadius: CGFloat
    private let fillColor: UIColor

    init(cornerRadius: CGFloat, fillColor: UIColor) {
        self.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        self.fillColor = fillColor
        super.init(frame: .zero)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.applyShadowOnce(withCornerRadius: self.cornerRadius, andFillColor: self.fillColor)
    }
}
​
class RoundShadowButton: UIButton, RoundedShadowable {

    var shadowLayer: CAShapeLayer?
    private let cornerRadius: CGFloat
    private let fillColor: UIColor

    init(cornerRadius: CGFloat, fillColor: UIColor) {
        self.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        self.fillColor = fillColor
        super.init(frame: .zero)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.applyShadowOnce(withCornerRadius: self.cornerRadius, andFillColor: self.fillColor)
    }
}
```