# Create a rectangle with just two rounded corners in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I need to create a rectangle that have just two rounded corners in swift (Objective C code also ok).

At the moment my code is creating two rectangles with

```
CGPathCreateWithRoundedRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 60), 5, 5, nil);
```

and

```
CGPathCreateWithRoundedRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 60), 0, 0, nil);
```

and merging them (to have two right angle corners and two rounded ones) but I am not happy with the code and I am pretty sure there should be much better ways to do it.

I am new to iOS and graphical development and swift.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIBezierPath/bezierPathWithRoundedRect:byRoundingCorners:cornerRadii: `bezierPathWithRoundedRect:byRoundingCorners:cornerRadii:`

Comment: As usual there have been **many small changes in Swift*, eg capitalization of constants, etc etc.  Suggest scroll down to newest answer.

Comment: Check out my answer here, it'll cover everything:- [https://stackoverflow.com/a/68342661/9863222](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68342661/9863222)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In **Swift 2.3** you could do so by

```
let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: anyView.bounds,
            byRoundingCorners: [.BottomLeft, .BottomRight],
            cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 10.0))

let shape = CAShapeLayer()
shape.path = maskPath.CGPath
view.layer.mask = shape
```

---

In **Objective-C** you could use the `UIBezierPath` class method

```
bezierPathWithRoundedRect:byRoundingCorners:cornerRadii:
```

example implementation-

```
// set the corner radius to the specified corners of the passed container
- (void)setMaskTo:(UIView*)view byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCorner)corners
{
    UIBezierPath *rounded = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:view.bounds
                                                  byRoundingCorners:corners
                                                        cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];
    CAShapeLayer *shape = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    [shape setPath:rounded.CGPath];
    view.layer.mask = shape;
}
```

and call the above method as-

```
[self setMaskTo:anyView byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight];
```

Comment: I could solve my problem with your answer. But just curious as I was trying to use the UIBezierPath.addArcWithCenter to draw the rounded corners myself and the start and end angle doesn't match at all the ones documented on https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009276-CH1-SW50

Comment: are you asking about using start and end angles?

Comment: #define RADIANS(degrees) ((degrees) / (180.0 / M_PI))

Comment: and use as -
double startAngle = RADIANS(45);
double endAngle = RADIANS(135);

Comment: perfect, it's definitely usable in swift as #define in objective-c

Comment: how do you do this in swift 2.0? the "|" doesn't appear to work.

Comment: not working for bottom. i.e. bottomLeft & bottomRight

Comment: not working in Swift 4. Using [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight] I have rounded only bottomLeft corner.

Comment: Work for me, topLeft and topRight corners, swift 4.0

Answer (score 70):

Update: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50396485/308315) below for Swift 4 / iOS 11 which is much, much easier

---

Here's a quick Swift 3 extension you can use to do rounding and optional borders.

Note: if you're using autolayout, you may need to call this in one of the view lifecycle callbacks like `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or `layoutSubviews` after the view has been constrained.

```
import UIKit

extension UIView {
    
    /**
     Rounds the given set of corners to the specified radius
     
     - parameter corners: Corners to round
     - parameter radius:  Radius to round to
     */
    func round(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        _ = _round(corners: corners, radius: radius)
    }
    
    /**
     Rounds the given set of corners to the specified radius with a border
     
     - parameter corners:     Corners to round
     - parameter radius:      Radius to round to
     - parameter borderColor: The border color
     - parameter borderWidth: The border width
     */
    func round(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat, borderColor: UIColor, borderWidth: CGFloat) {
        let mask = _round(corners: corners, radius: radius)
        addBorder(mask: mask, borderColor: borderColor, borderWidth: borderWidth)
    }
    
    /**
     Fully rounds an autolayout view (e.g. one with no known frame) with the given diameter and border
     
     - parameter diameter:    The view's diameter
     - parameter borderColor: The border color
     - parameter borderWidth: The border width
     */
    func fullyRound(diameter: CGFloat, borderColor: UIColor, borderWidth: CGFloat) {
        layer.masksToBounds = true
        layer.cornerRadius = diameter / 2
        layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor;
    }
    
}

private extension UIView {
    
    @discardableResult func _round(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) -> CAShapeLayer {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
        return mask
    }
    
    func addBorder(mask: CAShapeLayer, borderColor: UIColor, borderWidth: CGFloat) {
        let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        borderLayer.path = mask.path
        borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        borderLayer.strokeColor = borderColor.cgColor
        borderLayer.lineWidth = borderWidth
        borderLayer.frame = bounds
        layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I'm using this on a UITextField but it alters the width of the text field. Why does it change the width (which was set using Autolayout).

Comment: Update: just had to call the extension in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: @Onichan I added a `fullyRound` method that works for autolayout views as well since the frame isn't setup if called from `viewDidLoad` code

Comment: @DaveG Works with any UIView subclass (such as UIButton, UILabel, UITextField, etc)

Comment: sth wrong with the bottom using as [.bottomLeft, .topLeft] for radius

Comment: @Dincer Looks normal to me. Playground: https://gist.github.com/iwasrobbed/6ebd47d64b921ca27809adaafb4cce83 / http://imgur.com/xZCZmO4 ... Could you be more specific please?

Comment: @iwasrobbed I am calling the round method on a button inside `override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()` and it is introducing a lot of lag as well as adjusted the position/shrank the button. Also have attempted : `@IBOutlet fileprivate weak var button: UIButton! { didSet {
        button.round(corners: [.topRight, .bottomLeft], radius: 50 , borderColor: UIColor.blue, borderWidth: 5.0)
        button.layoutSubviews()
        } } ` the lag is now gone but the button is still shrunk/not constrained properly. Thanks!
Thanks!

Comment: I had to set self.layer.masksToBounds = true in the view before invoking round() method to show the changes.

Comment: Be careful with the `addBorder(mask:borderColor:borderWidth:)` method because it's always adding a new layer. If `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or `layoutSubviews` is called 5 times using the `round(corners:radius:borderColor:borderWidth:)` method in an empty UIView... that view will have 5 sublayers!

Comment: Have in mind that the `lineWidth` doesn't check the screen scale, so the `borderWidth` should be multiplied with `UIScreen.main.scale`.

Comment: How to use this when my view size is dynamic? lets say multiline label. When should I call the function to round?

Comment: @Dari See above: in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` lifecycle callback

Comment: @iwasrobbed Only works for topLeft and bottomLeft. Not working for right side, i.e., topRight, bottomRight. Any suggestion.

Answer (score 69):

**Swift 4+, iOS 11+**

If you already have a `UIView` named `myView` referenced as an `IBOutlet`, try adding the following two lines in `ViewDidLoad()` or wherever it's being loaded:

```
myView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
myView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
```

You can change the array `[]` to any combination of `MinX`, `MinY`, `MaxX`, and `MaxY` to select the desired corners. The above example rounds the bottom two corners.

This is just another approach, can be a bit simpler depending on your design.

Comment: big caveat, this solution is only iOS 11+

Comment: For top two corners you can use  view.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]

Comment: Great one thanks. While the naming like layerMinXMinYCorner is technically correct I wonder why Swift has to be that ugly at times

Answer (score 26):

**Swift 3** - Useful `UIView` extension when you need to round specific corners of some views:

```
extension UIView {
  func round(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.path = path.cgPath
    self.layer.mask = mask
  }
}
```

then just use it like this:

```
someView.round(corners: [.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 5)
```

Comment: how can set border or shadow to this view ?

Comment: @VadlapalliMasthan the same way you usually would. Just make sure the frame of the view is set before rounding corners and applying shadow and border

Answer (score 11):

Building on top of Sanjay's excellent answer, I wrote a quick CALayer extension for Swift 2.3, in case you need to do this sort of "only round some corners" thing more than once.

```
extension CALayer {
  func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
    let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds,
                                byRoundingCorners: corners,
                                cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))

    let shape = CAShapeLayer()
    shape.path = maskPath.CGPath
    mask = shape
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
myView.layer.roundCorners([.TopLeft, .TopRight], radius: myCornerRadius)
```

Swift 3.0 (In this example the bounds came from the view not from the layer. Using the bounds from the view make this code to work with views in a UITableViewCell.):

```
func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat, viewBounds: CGRect) {

    let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: viewBounds,
                                byRoundingCorners: corners,
                                cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))

    let shape = CAShapeLayer()
    shape.path = maskPath.cgPath
    mask = shape
}
```

Usage:

```
myView.layer.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft, .topRight], radius: myCornerRadius, viewBounds: bounds)
```

Comment: (good one - as usual there have been many small changes in Swift, eg capitalization of constants, etc)

Comment: For me, sometimes the image wouldn't show when I rounded the top corners, so I needed to add myView.layoutIfNeeded() to the line before.

Comment: hi @satoukum - the correct way to handle that in modern Xcode is shown in my answer below, cheers

Answer (score 9):

## Up-to-date for 2021 ...

Please note that syntax/systems have changed a lot since this question was asked a long time ago!

[image]

```
import UIKit
@IBDesignable
class RoundedEnds: UIView {
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setup()
    }
    
    func setup() {
        let r = self.bounds.size.height / 2
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, cornerRadius:r)
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

For only some corners, just change the `path` line of code to:

[image]

```
    let path = UIBezierPath(
        roundedRect: self.bounds,
        byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft,.topRight],
        cornerRadii: CGSize(width: r, height: r))
```

Answer (score 9):

> iOS 11+ Only | You can check iOS usage stats [here](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/)

## Explanation

Since the `CACornerMask` rawValue is an `UInt` you know that a `CACornerMask` *rawValue* is the sum of each `CACornerMask.Element` *rawValue*

More specifically:

- TopLeft     (`layerMinXMinYCorner`) = 1
- TopRight    (`layerMaxXMinYCorner`) = 2
- BottomLeft  (`layerMinXMaxYCorner`) = 4
- BottomRight (`layerMaxXMaxYCorner`) = 8

So for example if you want **top left** and **top right** corners you can just type `CACornerMask(rawValue: 3)`.

---

## Example

Below is a simple extension of `UIView`

```
extension UIView {
    enum Corner:Int {
        case bottomRight = 0,
        topRight,
        bottomLeft,
        topLeft
    }
    
    private func parseCorner(corner: Corner) -> CACornerMask.Element {
        let corners: [CACornerMask.Element] = [.layerMaxXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner]
        return corners[corner.rawValue]
    }
    
    private func createMask(corners: [Corner]) -> UInt {
        return corners.reduce(0, { (a, b) -> UInt in
            return a + parseCorner(corner: b).rawValue
        })
    }
    
    func roundCorners(corners: [Corner], amount: CGFloat = 5) {
        layer.cornerRadius = amount
        let maskedCorners: CACornerMask = CACornerMask(rawValue: createMask(corners: corners))
        layer.maskedCorners = maskedCorners
    }
}
```

You can use it this like:

```
let myRect = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50))
myRect.roundCorners(corners: [.topRight, .topLeft])
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is what you do in **Swift 2.0**

```
var maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: anyView.bounds,
        byRoundingCorners: [.BottomLeft, .BottomRight],
        cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 10.0))
```

Comment: not working for bottom. i.e. bottomLeft & bottomRight

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4:**

```
let maskPath = UIBezierPath(
            roundedRect: view.bounds,
            byRoundingCorners: [.allCorners],
            cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 10.0)
        )

let shape = CAShapeLayer()
shape.path = maskPath.cgPath

view.layer.mask = shape
```

Comment: what If I want only three of four corners? [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight, .topRight] not working.

Answer (score 3):

Updated iWasRobbed's answer to work with the Swift 3.0 GM version:

```
import UIKit

extension UIView {

    /**
     Rounds the given set of corners to the specified radius

     - parameter corners: Corners to round
     - parameter radius:  Radius to round to
     */
    func round(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        _round(corners: corners, radius: radius)
    }

    /**
     Rounds the given set of corners to the specified radius with a border

     - parameter corners:     Corners to round
     - parameter radius:      Radius to round to
     - parameter borderColor: The border color
     - parameter borderWidth: The border width
     */
    func round(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat, borderColor: UIColor, borderWidth: CGFloat) {
        let mask = _round(corners: corners, radius: radius)
        addBorder(mask: mask, borderColor: borderColor, borderWidth: borderWidth)
    }

    /**
     Fully rounds an autolayout view (e.g. one with no known frame) with the given diameter and border

     - parameter diameter:    The view's diameter
     - parameter borderColor: The border color
     - parameter borderWidth: The border width
     */
    func fullyRound(diameter: CGFloat, borderColor: UIColor, borderWidth: CGFloat) {
        layer.masksToBounds = true
        layer.cornerRadius = diameter / 2
        layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor;
    }

}

private extension UIView {

    @discardableResult func _round(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) -> CAShapeLayer {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
        return mask
    }

    func addBorder(mask: CAShapeLayer, borderColor: UIColor, borderWidth: CGFloat) {
        let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        borderLayer.path = mask.path
        borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        borderLayer.strokeColor = borderColor.cgColor
        borderLayer.lineWidth = borderWidth
        borderLayer.frame = bounds
        layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```swift
extension CACornerMask {

    public static var leftBottom     : CACornerMask { get { return .layerMinXMaxYCorner}}
    public static var rightBottom    : CACornerMask { get { return .layerMaxXMaxYCorner}}
    public static var leftTop        : CACornerMask { get { return .layerMaxXMinYCorner}}
    public static var rightTop       : CACornerMask { get { return .layerMinXMinYCorner}}
}

extension CALayer {

    func roundCorners(_ mask:CACornerMask,corner:CGFloat) {
        self.maskedCorners = mask
        self.cornerRadius = corner
    }
}

self.viewBack.layer.roundCorners([.leftBottom,.rightBottom], corner: 23)
```

Comment: Hi Mohammad Akbari, welcome. Please consider adding an explanation and format the code properly.

Answer (score 1):

In summary, you can create pretty extension like this:

```
extension UIView {

    func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: Double) {
        let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.path = maskPath.cgPath
        layer.mask = shape
    }

}
```

Use it like this:

```
view.roundCorners([.topRight, .bottomRight], radius: 10)
```

Here is all corners values:

- .topLeft
- .topRight
- .bottomLeft
- .bottomRight

Answer (score 1):

```
view.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
view.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner]
```

> ***Best way to do it!***

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5:** For top-left and top-right round corners.

```
yourView.layer.cornerRadius = 12
yourView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
```

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C version of iWasRobbed's answer:

UIView+RoundCorners.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIView (RoundCorners)

/**
 Rounds the given set of corners to the specified radius

 - parameter corners: Corners to round
 - parameter radius:  Radius to round to
 */
- (void)roundCorners:(UIRectCorner)corners radius:(CGFloat)radius;

/**
 Rounds the given set of corners to the specified radius with a border

 - parameter corners:     Corners to round
 - parameter radius:      Radius to round to
 - parameter borderColor: The border color
 - parameter borderWidth: The border width
 */
- (void)roundCorners:(UIRectCorner)corners radius:(CGFloat)radius borderColor:(UIColor *)borderColor borderWidth:(CGFloat)borderWidth;

/**
 Fully rounds an autolayout view (e.g. one with no known frame) with the given diameter and border

 - parameter diameter:    The view's diameter
 - parameter borderColor: The border color
 - parameter borderWidth: The border width
 */
- (void)fullyRoundWithDiameter:(CGFloat)diameter borderColor:(UIColor *)borderColor borderWidth:(CGFloat)borderWidth;

@end
```

UIView+RoundCorners.m

```
#import "UIView+RoundCorners.h"

@implementation UIView (RoundCorners)

- (void)roundCorners:(UIRectCorner)corners radius:(CGFloat)radius {
    [self _roundCorners:corners radius:radius];
}

- (void)roundCorners:(UIRectCorner)corners radius:(CGFloat)radius borderColor:(UIColor *)borderColor borderWidth:(CGFloat)borderWidth {
    CAShapeLayer *mask = [self _roundCorners:corners radius:radius];
    [self addBorderWithMask:mask borderColor:borderColor borderWidth:borderWidth];
}

- (void)fullyRoundWithDiameter:(CGFloat)diameter borderColor:(UIColor *)borderColor borderWidth:(CGFloat)borderWidth {
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.layer.cornerRadius = diameter / 2;
    self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth;
    self.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor;
}

- (CAShapeLayer *)_roundCorners:(UIRectCorner)corners radius:(CGFloat)radius {
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds byRoundingCorners:corners cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(radius, radius)];
    CAShapeLayer *mask = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    mask.path = path.CGPath;
    self.layer.mask = mask;
    return mask;
}

- (void)addBorderWithMask:(CAShapeLayer *)mask borderColor:(UIColor *)borderColor borderWidth:(CGFloat)borderWidth {
    CAShapeLayer *borderLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    borderLayer.path = mask.path;
    borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor.CGColor;
    borderLayer.strokeColor = borderColor.CGColor;
    borderLayer.lineWidth = borderWidth;
    borderLayer.frame = self.bounds;
    [self.layer addSublayer:borderLayer];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple hack could be as following. Take views like below example in image. **Red View** will have rounded corners and **Yellow View** (inside Red View) will prevent the corners to be rounded

[image]

Now write below code for **Red View**.

```
        self.myView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
```

Make sure you don't write any code as **clipsToBounds = true** or **masksToBounds = true**.

Below image is the result

[image]

Placement of **Yellow View** will decide, which 2 corners will not be rounded. Hope this is easy to implement.