# Add a shadow with CAShapeLayer?

Tags: ios, calayer

I have a `CAShapeLayer` with bottom rounded corners only. What I want is to add a shadow at the bottom, but it's not working, even though the code looks obviously right. All it does it round the bottom corners but I don't see a shadow.

```
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).cgPath
    shapeLayer.path = path

    shapeLayer.shadowColor = UIColor(r: 233, g: 233, b: 233).cgColor
    shapeLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 2.8)
    shapeLayer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    shapeLayer.shadowRadius = 0.0
    shapeLayer.shouldRasterize = true
    shapeLayer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale

    layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    layer.mask = shapeLayer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `shapeLayer` is rounding the corners of your view because it's set as the layer's mask. You probably want to add it as a sublayer instead.

**Old:**

```
layer.mask = shapeLayer
```

**New:**

```
layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

I wrote another answer about adding a shadow to a view with rounded corners here if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41475658/6658553

Comment: thanks! I got an idea from this question. All I did was create a dummy background view with a drop shadow; and insert it into the view (using `insertSubView`) that had the rounded corners.

Comment: adding the sublayer  to my layer makes the view entirely black

Answer (score 2):

Another solution,

The following UIView extension will work with any shape you mask the view with

```
extension UIView {

  func addShadow() {
     self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
     let roundedShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
     let roundedMaskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,
                                       byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .bottomLeft, .bottomRight],
                                       cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 8, height: 8))

     roundedShapeLayer.frame = self.bounds
     roundedShapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
     roundedShapeLayer.path = roundedMaskPath.cgPath

     self.layer.insertSublayer(roundedShapeLayer, at: 0)

     self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4
     self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -0.1, height: 4)
     self.layer.shadowRadius = 3
     self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
   }
}
```