# UILabel layer background color partial fill unintended

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uilabel, fill

Currently the label displayed has a custom radius set for the top right and bottom right corners. However the background color the the label is not filling entirely.

Have attempted to set the layers `maskToBounds` property to true and false.
Attempted changing both the `dateLabel.backgroundColor` and `dateLabel.layer.backgroundColor` to the desired dark blue color programmatically that is defaulted in the storyboard in an attempt to refill the label with no success.

```
@IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel! { didSet { 
    dateLabel.round(corners: [.topRight, .bottomRight], radius: 15, borderColor: UIColor.cyan, borderWidth: 3.0)
    dateLabel.setNeedsLayout()
}}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    dateLabel.layoutIfNeeded()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    dateLabel.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
}
```

[image]

What could be the reason for a label not filling its view entirely and what solution is available?

Comment: Check if there are any view/label behind or above it in the storyboard. Or check if you are adding it programatically.

Comment: can you tell me what you have written to add the background color?

Comment: @Malav Soni Currently the UILabel is within a stack view. the code to round the edges can be found at the link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35621736/5434541)

Comment: @ebby94 the uilabel is inside a stack view. that stack view is on top of a map view.

Comment: @lifewithelliott Try setting the background color of the stack view to check if you're seeing the background of the stackview or the label.

Comment: @ebby94 stackviews cant have a background color set on them

Comment: @lifewithelliott Sorry, didn't know about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is definitely the use of corner function, it adds sublayers to your UIlable , each sublayer has it's own background colour, so you can either find another way of rounding corners without using that function which adds sublayers or in your viewDidLoad iterate through sublayers property of layer `layer.sublayers` which is an array of sublayers and apply your background colour to each of them, or add a function to that UIView extension ( corner function ) that does this king of colour assignment then call that function.