# How to create Right Angle View in Swift?

Tags: swift, uiview

I am able to create triangle view in swift using below code-

```
class TriangleView: UIView {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        // Get Height and Width
        let layerHeight = layer.frame.height
        let layerWidth = layer.frame.width

        // Create Path
        let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()

        // Draw Points
        bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: layerHeight))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: layerWidth, y: layerHeight))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: layerWidth / 2, y: 0))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: layerHeight))
        bezierPath.close()

        // Apply Color
        UIColor.red.setFill()
        bezierPath.fill()

        // Mask to Path
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.cgPath
        layer.mask = shapeLayer
    }

}

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let triangle = TriangleView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 55 , height: 60))
        triangle.backgroundColor = .white
        triangle.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi * 4.49)
        imageView.addSubview(triangle)

}
```

Now problem is that I want to change it to the right angle triangle using transform properties. How to achieve this?

**Expected Result**

[image]

**Current Result**

[image]

Comment: It [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29618760/create-a-rectangle-with-just-two-rounded-corners-in-swift) related?

Answer (score 4):

I hope you want this part.
[image]

Here is the code.

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    let path = UIBezierPath.init()

    // top left
    path.move(to: .zero)

    // top right
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width,
                             y: 0))

    // bottom left offset
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width * 0.1,
                             y: bounds.size.height))

    // bottom left
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0,
                             y: bounds.size.height))

    // top left
    path.close()

    // change fill color here.
    UIColor.black.setFill()
    path.fill()
}
```

**Result**
[image]

**How I drew**

[image]

**Modification**

If you change the code `UIColor.black.setFill()` to

```
let fillColor = UIColor(red: 0xF9/0xff, green: 0x0D/0xff, blue: 0x5A/0xff, alpha: 1)
    fillColor.setFill()
```

you get this result.
[image]

Have fun coding.

Answer (score 2):

[image: image of triangles]

You're currently drawing 'a'. You want to draw 'b'.

```
extension UIBezierPath {

    convenience init(rightAngledTriangleInRect: CGRect, offset withOffset: CGFloat) {
        self.init()
        move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))
        addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
        addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX + offset, y: rect.maxY))
        addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
        addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))
        close()
    }
}
```

Then use by:

```
let path = UIBezierPath.init(rightAngledTriangleInRect: rect, withOffset: 20.0)
```

Note that there's no need to add `self.` in the convenience inits for the bezier path instructions.

If you're doing a lot of drawing, I'd recommend adding a number of these inits to make life easier.

To use in your current TriangleView:

```
class TriangleView: UIView {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        let path = UIBezierPath.init(rightAngledTriangleInRect: rect, withOffset: 20.0)
        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.path = path.cgPath

        // Set the mask
        layer.mask = shape
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please describe with example, How to use this code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

There are some easy way too for achivieng this but for using `transform` here is the sample code.use this transform instead of yours.it's sample code for having right angle triangle from your drawing:

```
triangle.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi).translatedBy(x: (triangle.bounds.width / 2), y: 0.0)
```

you should notice that `CGAffineTransform` rotate the view from it's origins

Comment: Working for the simple view, but not in tableview cell

Comment: @iDeveloper there is no problem in tableViewCell.i tested.be sure to add `tableView.addSubView(triangle)`