# How to add a custom shape to an UIImageView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I'm trying to add a custom shape to an `imageView`. Please check the below images.

This is the required one:

[image: Required Image Shape]

This is what I have done so far:

[image: Current Image Shape]

I'm new to `Core Graphics` and I have done this so far:

```
    private func customImageClipper(imageV: UIImageView){

    let path = UIBezierPath()

    let size = imageV.frame.size

    print(size)

    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: size.height))

    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.8, y: size.height/2))

    path.close()

    let shape = CAShapeLayer()

    shape.path = path.cgPath

    imageV.layer.sublayers = [shape]

}
```

I'm creating a function to achieve a shape like this, but whenever I pass the `imageView` into this function, I can not see any change at all. I know that I have to move from points to another point to achieve this shape, but I have never done this. Any help would be appreciated. This is how I'm calling this function:

```
imageV.layoutIfNeeded()

customImageClipper(imageV: imageV)
```

P.S.: I'm not using `Storyboard`, I have created this programmatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways to create shapes using UIBezierPaths. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53257685/how-to-create-right-angle-view-in-swift) post here discusses the use of the `draw` function to create a shape.

Here is an example using your `clip` function within the cell.

```
func clip(imageView: UIView, withOffset offset: CGFloat) {
    let path = UIBezierPath()

    //Move to Top Left
    path.move(to: .init(x: imageView.bounds.size.width * offset, y: 0))

    //Draw line from Top Left to Top Right
    path.addLine(to: .init(x: imageView.bounds.size.width, y: 0))

    //Draw Line from Top Right to Bottom Right
    path.addLine(to: .init(x: imageView.bounds.size.width * (1 - offset), y: imageView.bounds.size.height))

    //Draw Line from Bottom Right to Bottom Left
    path.addLine(to: .init(x: 0, y: imageView.bounds.size.height))

    //Close Path
    path.close()

    //Create the Shape Mask for the ImageView
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    imageView.layer.mask = shapeLayer
}
```

In this function, the offset is the amount of angle you would like on the shape, ranging from 0 to 1. (0.4) seems to work for your requirements.

This shares a lot of similarities with Apseri's answer, except I chose the route of percentages, rather than exact size. Nothing wrong with either approach, I just found it easier to understand with percentages. :)

One last note to point out, I used this function in the `layoutSubviews` function.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    imageView.layoutIfNeeded()
    clip(imageView: self.imageView, withOffset: 0.4)
}
```

This output the following image:

[image: Image of a cell showing custom shape]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. But, why have you used `layoutSubviews()`?

Comment: Because I used auto layout constraints to set out my view. Until layoutSubviews, the imageView doesn’t know what size it’s frame is. Therefore the frame would be zero and the function wouldn’t work. :)

Comment: Doesn't `layoutifNeeded()` gives the frame size?

Comment: Hmm, turns out, I was wrong. I was under the impression that layoutIfNeeded simply notified the UI to update. I can edit the answer if you like. I just moved the layoutIfNeeded and function call into the init of the (i assume) table cell.

Answer (score 2):

Here is example of some path clipping. Of course path can be also put via parameters, and this can be applied to any view, as shown.

Before:

[image]

After (grey background is below ScrollView background):

[image]

```
func customImageClipper(imageV: UIView){

    let path = UIBezierPath()
    let size = imageV.frame.size

    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: size.width/3.0, y: 0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: size.width/3.0 + 50, y: 0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: size.width/3.0, y: size.height))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: size.width/3.0 - 50, y: size.height))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: size.width/3.0, y: 0))
    path.close()

    let shape = CAShapeLayer()
    shape.path = path.cgPath
    shape.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

    imageV.layer.mask = shape
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1- Subclassing your UIImageView**

**2- implement your custom drawings inside setNeedsLayout using UIBezierPath**

```
class MyCustomImageView: UIImageView {  



    override func setNeedsLayout() {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width, y: self.frame.size.height/2))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: 0))
        path.addArcWithCenter(CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height/2), radius: self.frame.size.width/2, startAngle:-CGFloat(M_PI_2), endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI_2), clockwise: false)

        path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height))
        path.closePath()
        UIColor.redColor().setFill()
        path.stroke()
        path.bezierPathByReversingPath()
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.frame = self.bounds
        shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        self.layer.mask = shapeLayer;
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true;
    }

}
```