# Hiding and showing UILabel with rounded corner and shadow in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I am using this method [Swift - Problems with corner radius and drop shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644802/swift-problems-with-corner-radius-and-drop-shadow) to add rounded corners and shadow to a UILabel.

However, I need to hide and unhide the label depending on content. I am setting hidden true/false in my ViewController class. But the shadow layer still shows.

See example images below.

[image]

What is the best way to hide/unhide this shadow layer as well?

Comment: Set the alpha to 0. View.alpha = 0

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the alpha to 0:

```
myLabel.alpha = 0
```