# UILabel with layer Corner radius AND shadow

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uilabel

i'm looking for a way to display a `UILabel` with `layer.cornerRadius` and `layer.shadow`.

I figured out, that with `label.clipsToBounds = true` the `cornerRadius` will be set and with `label.masksToBounds = false` the shadow will be displayed

With both only the shadow, without the cornerRadius will be displayed

```
let label = UILabel()
label.textAlignment = .center
label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 32, weight: .regular)
label.textColor = .white
label.clipsToBounds = true
label.backgroundColor = Colors.Vibrants.softBlue
label.layer.cornerRadius = 50
label.layer.masksToBounds = false
label.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
label.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5, height: 5)
label.layer.shadowRadius = 5
label.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
label.text = "0"
```

Can anyone solve this, so that the `cornerRadius` AND the `shadow` will be displayed?

Comment: Is it `label label = UILabel()` or `let label = UILabel()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - Problems with corner radius and drop shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644802/swift-problems-with-corner-radius-and-drop-shadow)

Comment: @1 sry yes, copied wrong :/

Comment: Where are u setting Its frame?

Comment: @EmreÖnder I tried setting the radius right after setting the frame and it didn't work. do you have a solution for that?

Comment: Can you please try it in layoutSubviews

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try adding a parent `UIView` for your label that will contain the background color and cornerRadius. Then retain the shadow properties to the label

Answer (score 2):

```
    label.layer.borderWidth = 0.2
    label.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    label.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    label.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: CGFloat(1.0), height: CGFloat(2.0))
    label.layer.shadowRadius = 1
    label.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
    label.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    label.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class setShadowOnLabel: UILabel
{
    override func layoutSubviews()
    {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.2)
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.80
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
    }
}
```

Then directly assign setShadowOnLabel class to Label.[image]

[image]