# UIButton with background image, rounded corners and a shadow

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, shadow, rounded-corners

I'm trying to create a UIButton with rounded corners, a background image and a shadow. Before adding the shadow, everything works fine.

[image]

But after adding shadow values, the shadow doesn't show up. Obviously due to `clipsToBounds` property value being set to `true`. If I remove that, it looks like this.

[image]

Since I need the corner radius as well, I cannot have the `clipsToBounds` be `false`.

This is my code.

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {
    
    var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
            clipsToBounds = true
        }
    }
    
    var shadowRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.shadowRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.shadowRadius = newValue
        }
    }
    
    var shadowOpacity: Float {
        get {
            return layer.shadowOpacity
        }
        set {
            layer.shadowOpacity = newValue
        }
    }
    
    var shadowOffset: CGSize {
        get {
            return layer.shadowOffset
        }
        set {
            layer.shadowOffset = newValue
        }
    }
    
    var shadowColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            if let color = layer.shadowColor {
                return UIColor(cgColor: color)
            }
            return nil
        }
        set {
            if let color = newValue {
                layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
            } else {
                layer.shadowColor = nil
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        
    }
    
}


private lazy var button: CustomButton = {
    let button = CustomButton()
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "Rectangle"), for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    button.setTitle("Sign Up", for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .semibold)
    button.cornerRadius = 20
    button.shadowColor = .systemGreen
    button.shadowRadius = 10
    button.shadowOpacity = 1
    button.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    return button
}()
```

Is there a workaround to have both the shadow and the corner radius?

[Demo project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ci941bee28zfr9/button%20demo.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it via adding shadow and background image with different layer.

First, if you don't need the properties, remove all and modify your `CustomButton` implementation just like below (modify as your need):

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {
    
    private let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 20
    private var imageLayer: CALayer!
    private var shadowLayer: CALayer!
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        addShadowsLayers(rect)
    }
    
    private func addShadowsLayers(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Add Image
        if self.imageLayer == nil {
            let imageLayer = CALayer()
            imageLayer.frame = rect
            imageLayer.contents = UIImage(named: "Rectangle")?.cgImage
            imageLayer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
            imageLayer.masksToBounds = true
            layer.insertSublayer(imageLayer, at: 0)
            self.imageLayer = imageLayer
        }
        
        // Set the shadow
        if self.shadowLayer == nil {
            let shadowLayer = CALayer()
            shadowLayer.masksToBounds = false
            shadowLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.systemGreen.cgColor
            shadowLayer.shadowOffset = .zero
            shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 1
            shadowLayer.shadowRadius = 10
            shadowLayer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: cornerRadius).cgPath
            layer.insertSublayer(shadowLayer, at: 0)
            self.shadowLayer = shadowLayer
        }
    }
}
```

And initialize your button like below:

```
private lazy var button: CustomButton = {
    let button = CustomButton()
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    button.setTitle("Sign Up", for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .semibold)
    return button
}()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is great. But the thing is if I remove the properties, I end up hardcoding the values inside the button class itself. I'm hoping to make it more of a generic solution. So I can set the shadow/background image values when initialising the button.

Comment: Update: I modified your code like [this](https://pastebin.com/VWRfuPGH) by exposing the properties. Still works great. However I noticed a small problem with the shadow. If I reduce the shadow radius, The shadow doesn't have the same corner radius. [See](https://i.imgur.com/6EMl34D.png). Any idea why that may be? This issue exists in the original code as well. I tried adding the `cornerRadius` value to the `shadowLayer` as well, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Did you give same radius for both? I made a small update for that. (btw i can not access to first link). you can edit/extend any part of the code as your need, i just keep the  required part for what i did.

Comment: Please check now. [link](http://pastie.org/p/0ugkeKMF75NW652vYfRR3z). The `cornerRadius` and `shadowRadius` are different, right? Since shadow radius handles the blur radius of the shadow, I set it to 2. That's when I noticed the squared edges of the shadow. The corner radius is still set to 20. No issue with that.

Comment: Yes you are right, I modified `shadowLayer.shadowPath` line.

Comment: @omerfarukozturk how to add press animation in your CustomButton class? please help. Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to use the root layer (by calling `setBackgroundImage`) so we only have 1 sublayer (the shadow's)? Since we can use it to set different images for different states.

Comment: I just tried this out, and it seems like 2 things to note: the sublayer position matters (index 0 is rendered on screen first hence shadow should there), and for some reason `imageLayer.contents` does not work for me for some reason and I realised I was using an `UIImage` instead of `cgImage`. Also it seems like this sublayers solution does not work with the `setBackgroundImage` which is unfortunate.. I think the workaround is to add a view manually behind the button itself.

Comment: I found the solution to it in another question (for reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/37687638/321629)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use two separate views for shadow and image. I can't find any solution to set image, shadow, and corner radius using the same button layer.

Make button's corner radius(clipsToBounds=true) rounded and set the image on it.

Take a shadow view under the button with proper shadow radius and offset.

Answer (score 0):

You can add view.layer.masksToBounds = false

This will disable clipping for sublayer

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410896-maskstobounds