# `CALayer.cornerRadius` doesn't work if `masksToBounds = false` - it WAS fixed! But when?

Tags: uikit, core-animation, rounded-corners

Colleagues - there used to be a bug with CoreAnimation!

If you set `masksToBounds = false`, `cornerRadius` will not work.
But if you set `masksToBounds = true`, then shadows won't work.

And this bug was FIXED at some point between 2018 and 2020.
My question is WHEN it was fixed? I would really like to know exact release note for something, maybe an iOS version or Swift version, which introduced this fix, and how they formulated it.

Comment: From what I can tell, it was never fixed, since people are still using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644802/swift-problems-with-corner-radius-and-drop-shadow)

Comment: @Shidouuu I checked it out and -- nope, there is a tad of misunderstanding going on - there are answers that rely on the fixed behavior too. And I know for a fact, it is indeed fixed, I've written production code like 3 weeks ago utilizing the fixed behavior

Comment: Can confirm that `layer.cornerRadius` works even without setting `layer.masksToBounds = true`. I was confused why did it start working. Googling brought me to this page.