# Masking a UIView and Auto Layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout

I have a UIView that I want to mask with another UIView, punching a hole out of its center. Here's my `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[self.view addSubview:self.viewToMask];
[self.view addSubview:self.theMask];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.viewToMask attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.viewToMask attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[cyan(200)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"cyan": self.viewToMask}]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[cyan(200)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"cyan": self.viewToMask}]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.theMask attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.viewToMask attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.theMask attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.viewToMask attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[mask(100)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"mask": self.theMask}]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[mask(100)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"mask": self.theMask}]];
}
```

It gives me exactly what I'm looking for, minus the masking:

[image: views without masking]

If I add one more line:

```
[self.viewToMask setMaskView:self.theMask];
```

both views disappear --- the small view (`self.theMask`) masks out the whole larger view (`self.viewToMask`) even though it's only half the size. Does anyone understand what's going on here? Can you not use `UIView.maskView` with Auto Layout?

Comment: I know when you use the pre-iOS 8 version of this (`-[CALayer maskLayer]`), you had to position the masked layer’s coordinate space, and the mask layer doesn’t exist in the normal view hierarchy. I wonder if something similar is going on here?

Comment: That's totally what's going on here. Thanks a lot.

Comment: So how did it work out? Can you use Auto Layout with a `maskView`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Zev explained, the mask view lives outside of the ordinary view hierarchy and so can't be used together with Auto Layout. I got around this by placing it manually in my view controller's `viewDidLayoutSubviews`:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    CGRect viewToMaskRect = self.viewToMask.bounds;
    CGRect maskRect = CGRectMake(viewToMaskRect.origin.x + 50.0, viewToMaskRect.origin.y + 50.0, 100.0, 100.0);
    [self.theMask setFrame:maskRect];
    [self.viewToMask setMaskView:self.theMask];
}
```

[image: proper masking]

Comment: Cool. Although that doesn't look like the hole punched in the center you said you were going for…?

Comment: Yeah, masking is the inverse of what I thought (clear pixels let the subviews of the view you're masking show through). I used this solution to get the hole punch effect: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859285/uibezierpath-subtract-path

Answer (score 4):

Based on `Russ'` answer I did my own research and got an alternative workaround.

The code sample below will mask the left and right side of the main view with 10pt. Important

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        self.setupMaskView()
    }

    private func setupMaskView() {

        let maskView = UIView()
        maskView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        maskView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)

        let maskContainerView = UIView()
        maskContainerView.addSubview(maskView)

        self.view.addSubview(maskContainerView)

        maskView.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 10).active = true
        maskView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.widthAnchor, constant: -20).active = true
        maskView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.heightAnchor).active = true

        self.view.maskView = maskContainerView // this will not work it we place this line above the constraint code !!!
        /* I have no idea why this does not work and why nesting is required, maybe some sort of bug? */
    }
}
```

This code is using AutoLayout syntax available from iOS 9.0 and Swift 2.0. (Written in Xcode 7 beta 4)

Comment: This is actually a very clever trick! As for the comment in code - you cannot set constraint when view is not in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

You can make auto layout work with your maskView by making the maskView just a normal subview (Eg. in a storyboard with relevant constraints) then only setting it as maskView in viewWillLayoutSubviews. Ie:

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    self.viewToBeMasked.maskView = self.maskViewWithLayoutConstraints;
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me without nesting the mask view. It is kinda strange. :/ I'll post it as an alternative answer.