# How to subtract the intersection of UIBezierPath A&B from A?

Tags: ios, swift, vector, drawing, uibezierpath

Suppose we have two UIBezierPaths, path1 and path2... (that have already been defined relative to view bounds at runtime and already exist as properties of the same view).

We want to get a new path of type UIBezierPath, path3, that is the result of subtracting path2 from path1:

[image]

The way this is done (as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859285/uibezierpath-subtract-path)) is to do this:

```
path1.append(path2.reversing())
```

BUT, that only seems to work for circumstances where path1 fully encompasses path2.

For example, consider the case where there is only a partial intersection -- path1 does not fully encompass path2.  This is what happens if we apply the same method as above:

[image]

In Android, the answer is:

```
path1.op(path2, Path.Op.DIFFERENCE);
```

So... is there an equivalent simple operation in IOS?

If not, is there a function that could be written as:

```
func returnPath2CutOutOfPath1(path1: UIBezierPath, path2: UiBezierPath) -> UIBezierPath {

// the mystery lies within these here parts. :)

}
```

Comment: Please post code which you have tried.

Comment: Is it sufficient to fill the difference or do you need the resulting UIBezierPath for a different reason?

Comment: Ideally it would be as if the second path is literally cut out of the first... that way, the normal practices of applying outlines, backgrounds, and outline widths etc. can still be applied properly to the resulting path.

Comment: Maybe you can refer to a similar post - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859285/uibezierpath-subtract-path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859285/uibezierpath-subtract-path)

Comment: I read that before I posted this... in fact that's whereI learned the best solution I had found, yet: "path1.append(path2.reversing())"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to get the differences of UIBezierPaths as a new path on iOS.

**Testcase**

```
private func path2() -> UIBezierPath {
    return UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 100, y: 50, width: 200, height: 200))
}

private func path1() -> UIBezierPath {
    return UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 50, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200))
}
```

Starting point: to simply show which path represents what: path 1 is yellow and path 2 is green:

[image: starting point]

**Possiblity 1**

You have probably already seen this possibility: In the link you mentioned in your question, there is also a clever solution if you only have to perform a fill operation.

The code was taken from this answer (from the link you posted) https://stackoverflow.com/a/8860341 - only converted to Swift:

```
func fillDifference(path2: UIBezierPath, path1: UIBezierPath) {
    let clipPath = UIBezierPath.init(rect: .infinite)
    clipPath.append(path2)
    clipPath.usesEvenOddFillRule = true

    UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.saveGState()
    clipPath.addClip()
    path1.fill()
    UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.restoreGState()
}
```

So this fills a path, but does not return a UIBezierPath, which means that you cannot apply outlines, backgrounds, contour widths, etc., because the result is not a UIBezierPath.

It looks like this:

[image: fill only]

**Possiblity 2**

You can use a third-party library, e.g. one from an author named Adam Wulf here: https://github.com/adamwulf/ClippingBezier.

The library is written in Objective-C, but can be called from Swift.

In Swift, it would look like this:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let result = self.path1().difference(with: self.path2())

    for p in result ?? [] {
        p.stroke()
    }
}
```

If you want to use this library, you have to note a small hint: in Other Linker Flags in the project settings, as described by the readme, "-ObjC++ -lstdc++" must be added, otherwise it would be built without complaints, but would silently not load the frameworks and eventually crash, since the UIBEzierPath categories are not found.

The result looks like this:

[image: real bezier path result]

So this would actually give your desired result, but you would have to use a 3rd party library.

Answer (score 2):

I have achieved you desired solution, but I have created code for static view of size 200x200.

Let me show you what I have tried and tell me how useful for you.

First of all, I have create class of custom view where I have wrote code to draw view. See the following code:

```
class MyCustomView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {

        // Create a CAShapeLayer
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

        let path1 = self.path1()
        let path2 = self.path2()

        // Append path2 to path1
        path1.append(path2.reversing())

        // Set true of Even Odd Fill Rule
        path1.usesEvenOddFillRule = true

        // Call this method to add clip in path
        path1.addClip()

        shapeLayer.path = path1.cgPath

        // Apply other properties related to the path
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
        shapeLayer.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

        // Add the new layer to our custom view
        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------
    // This is static code as I have already told you first.
    // Create First UIBezierPath,

    func path1() -> UIBezierPath {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 200))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 0))
        path.close()
        return path
    }

    // Create Second UIBezierPath
    func path2() -> UIBezierPath {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: -50))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 150))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 250, y: 150))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 250, y: -50))
        path.close()
        return path
    }
}
```

This custom class code will create share layer with your **actual** result as you have described in figure 4.

Now to use this class I have create instance of above class with fixed height & width.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Create a new UIView and add it to the view controller
    let myView = MyCustomView()

    // Must set clipsToBounds true to remove extra layer which are display out side of view as like your **actual** result in figure 4.
    myView.clipsToBounds = true 
    myView.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200)
    myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
    view.addSubview(myView)
}
```

This will display view as follow which is your desired result.

[image: UIBezierPath Intersection]
I hope this will help you, let me know still if you have any query.

Comment: Thanks for the effort!  I will probably learn a thing or two from that, but I wrote a bad question that wasn't precise enough.  I have made some edits.  I apologize.